# Removing float duplicate in the same cell from a list python

Tags: python

I have a list with float number separate with a "," and I would like to remove it if it is repeated in the same cell.
Thanks.

`295091345,2034223
295096523,295096525,295096128,295096128 
295096523,295096525,40003, 40003`

`295091345,2034223
295096523,295096525,295096128
295096523,295096525,40003`


I'm trying to that but instead of string I would like to do it with float.

from collections import OrderedDict

`df['Desired'] = (df['Current'].str.split()
                              .apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys())
                              .str.join(','))`

Comment: You forgot to add your code. Please edit your question to add your non-working code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order)

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
list = [295096523,295096525,295096128,295096128]
new_list = []
[new_list.append(i) for i in list if i not in new_list]
```